# Controlling calling controller's public methods, is it possible?

Tags: php

The task is to protect calling **public** controller's methods; we need to check if user is administrator or not before calling.

```
class AdminController {

    final public function __call($name, $arguments) {
        if (!Auth::isAuth()) {
            $User = UserFactory::loadById(Auth::getUserId());
            if (!$User->isAdmin()) {
                throw new ForbiddenException();
            }
        }
        return call_user_func_array(array($this, $name), $arguments);
    }

}

class AdminCategoryController extends AdminController {

    public function view() { //__call() won't be called bacause it is public method

    }

}
```

We can use magic `__call()` method, but we need all methods to be `private`.

Another way I see is to define `final public __construct()` at `AdminController` and put checking $User->isAdmin() there...

Any other ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new method in your base controller (`BaseController`) called `isSecure()`:

```
public function isSecure() {
    return false;
}
```

Then in your controller that must be secure (`AdminBaseController`) override the method with:

```
public function isSecure() {
    return true;
}
```

`AdminBaseController` extends `BaseController` and `AdminCategoryController` should extend `AdminBaseController`.

Then at any point you can call `$Controller->isSecure()` on any controller to find out if it must be secure or not.

So in your dispatch code you could use something like this (obviously needs refactoring):

```
if($Controller->isSecure()) {
    if (!Auth::isAuth()) {
        $User = UserFactory::loadById(Auth::getUserId());
        if (!$User->isAdmin()) {
            throw new ForbiddenException();
        }
    } else {
        $Controller->view();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do we need to implement `isSecure` method? Being child of `AdminController` = all methods are securely called. Implementing `isSecure()` method is ok if I don't have separated controllers for Admin/Public. Btw, it seems to me that it is better to define `isSecure` at root controller and then define constanct `IS_SECURE` is every child controller.

Comment: So your dispatch code can check before calling the controller. Your dispatcher should direct the user to an `InvalidLoginController` or some such rather than to the `*AdminController` if they are not authorised. I was revising my answer slightly whilst you were commenting. I am suggesting you catch unauthenticated users a level up from the controller in your dispatch code.

Comment: Aha, I see. So, checking isCallable in dispatcher will allow us to implement full featured ACL. Great!